# Android Animation in Runnable

Tags: android, animation, runnable

New to animations. My goal is to have a thin black bar scroll from the top of the screen to the bottom every hour. I got my black bar scrolling based on a button press. I found a Runnable example which can repeatedly run an action. In my code my y callback function is being called but my animation is never started.

My black bar is a view, it is not visible.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/blackSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

My animation works really well when triggered from a button press

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

My runnable is created in my main activity

```
 occupancyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.occupancy_button);
        blackSlider = (View) findViewById(R.id.blackSlider);
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.screen_wipe_top_down);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                blackSlider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                blackSlider.bringToFront();
                getActionBar().hide();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                blackSlider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getActionBar().show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        OneShotRunner animationRunner = new OneShotRunner(5000, true);
        OneShotActionCallback animationRunnerCallback = new OneShotActionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onActionRun() {
                blackSlider.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        };

        animationRunner.setOneShotRunActionCallback(animationRunnerCallback);
        animationRunner.start();
```

If I use the occupancyButon on click listener the animation is triggered correctly. When starting from the runnable the animation start and end functions are never called. Can an animation not be run from a runnable? Am I initializing it incorrectly?

Comment: A comment on this. If I run the animation once before I start the runnable, then it works no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you start animations in the UI thread. Otherwise they may not work.